# multiprocessing - Influence of number on process on processing time

Tags: python, multiprocessing

It may be a really stupid question, but I didn't find any doc which perfectly answers that question. I'm trying to familiarise with the `multiprocessing` library on python try to paraglide task using `multiprocessing.Pool`.
I initiate the number of processes in my Pool with:
`Pool(processes=nmbr_of_processes)`.
The thing is I don't understand exactly how this number of process reduce the work duration time. I wrote a script to evaluate it.

```
def test_operation(y):
sum = 0
for x in range(1000):
    sum += y*x


def main():
    time1 = time.time()
    p = mp.Pool(processes=2)
    result = p.map(test_operation, range(100000))
    p.close()
    p.join()

print('Parallel tooks {} seconds'.format(time.time() - time1))

final = list()
time2 = time.time()
for y in range(100000):
    final.append(test_operation(y))
print('Serial tooks {} seconds'.format(time.time() - time2))
```

The thing is, when I'm using 2 processes with `mp.Pool(processes=2)` I get typically:

```
Parallel took 5.162384271621704 seconds
Serial took 9.853888034820557 seconds
```

And if I'm using more processes, like `p = mp.Pool(processes=4)`
I get:

```
Parallel took 6.404058218002319 seconds
Serial took 9.667300701141357 seconds
```

I'm working on a MacMini DualCore i7 3Ghz. I know I can't reduce the work duration time to half the time it took with a serial work. But I can't understand why adding more processes increase work duration time compared to a work with 2 processes. And if there is an optimal number of processes to start depending of the cpu, what would it be ?

Comment: What do you get from `mp.cpu_count()`?

Comment: I got 4. For the 4 logical cores I guess

Comment: So the general rule of thumb would be to have `mp.cpu_count() -1` processes, which leaves one core free for system tasks, so that you're less likely to have processes interfering with each other. Try your test with 3 processes.

Comment: I just made the test, it seems indeed slightly quicker with 3 cores than with 2 ! So, using 4 processes instead of 3 increase the work duration time because of interference between processes ?

Comment: Pretty much. Your task is CPU-bound and it's not the only thing that your system has to run, so there has to be some work from the system to schedule tasks so that everything can keep running. You're not just considering the Python processes that you spawn, you also have to consider everything else; generally leaving 1 core free gives the system enough flexibility to not get in the way of your processes.

Comment: That is a satisfying answer, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing to note here is that this applies to CPU-bound tasks; your code is heavy on CPU usage. The first thing to do is check how many theoretical cores you have:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
print(mp.cpu_count())
```

For CPU-bound tasks like this, there is no benefit to be gained by creating a pool with more workers than theoretical cores. If you don't specify the size of the `Pool`, it will default back to this number. However, this neglects something else; your code is not the only thing that your OS has to run.

If you launch as many processes as theoretical cores, the system has no choice but to interrupt your processes periodically simply to keep running, so you're likely to get a performance hit. You can't monopolise all cores. The general rule-of-thumb here is to have a pool size of `cpu_count() - 1`, which leaves the OS a core free to use on other processes.

I was surprised to find that other answers I found don't mention this general rule; it seems to be confined to comments etc. However, your own tests show that it is applicable to the performance in your case so is a reasonable heuristic to determine pool size.